# // comment not working on html line in a .php file

Tags: php, html, comments

When writing code in a .php file starting <?php, I can comment on the PHP script by adding // at the front of the line.

But when starting code with <!DOCTYPE  the // just doesn't work. When I comment with this <!--, it only comments out the HTML code and left alone, the php code.

I'm using PHPStorm 2023.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300italic,700,700italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.4.1/milligram.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column column-60 column-offset-20">
                <h1>Our first Form</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, dicta eligendi eveniet modi nostrum porro reiciendis suscipit tempora temporibus veniam?</p>

                <p>
                    <?php if (!empty($_POST['fname'])){ ?>
                    //First name: <?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?> <br>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if (!empty($_POST['lname'])): ?>
                    Last Name: <?php echo $_POST['lname']; ?><br>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </p>

                <div class="myForm">
                    <form method="POST">
                        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
                        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried both php comment and html comment, but nothing worked. Html comment just comment out the html codes not php script.

What I want: I want to use // to comment on any line on a .php file. Either it's a script or html codes inside a .php file.

Note: I'm very new at PHP in general. Please pardon any terms I've used that don't make any sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fname'])){ ?>
//First name: <?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?> <br>
<?php } ?>
```

Forward slashes do not have any special meaning in HTML. HTML comments look like `<!-- Your comment here -->`. To use PHP comments you need to write it as PHP code:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fname'])){ ?>
<?php //First name: <?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?> <br>?>
<?php } ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fname'])){ /*?>
First name: <?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?> <br>
<?php */} ?>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MNTEY#v8.2.11)

Comment: The issue is it's a .php file, not a .html file. // should work fundamentally on any line in a .PHP file. Isn't it? 

I've been following a tutorial where // worked as a comment on the instructor code but it doesn't work on my code.

Comment: The PHP interpreter does not care about file extensions. But if you save your file as .html and you haven't configured your web server to execute it as PHP, then PHP will not run at all. I think you have the misconception that text outside `<?php ... ?>` is also PHP code. That is not how PHP works.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've concluded. Not every single line is considered PHP code in a .PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

To comment out the line, use this:

```
 <!-- First name: <?php /* echo $_POST['fname']; */?> <br>  -->
```

Comment: Not working. It's ended up like this. HTML code was commented but not the PHP code.
http://prntscr.com/SGWgd0FLOjzq

Comment: You can modify it to work like this

<!-- First name: <?php /* echo $_POST['fname']; */?> <br>  -->